# Stack Overflow editor unable to properly format the code when it finds /* as a value of an XML tag

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I was going through the question *[HTTP to HTTPS redirection issue with Tomcat 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798406/http-to-https-redirection-issue-with-tomcat-8)* and found that the Stack Overflow editor unable to properly format the code when it finds `/*` as a value of an XML tag, and it is treating this a beginning of a comment and commented our rest of the portion.

See the below picture.

[image]

It is clearly a bug, and it should be resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax highlighting in a post is determined by what tags you use. Since that question was tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) then all syntax highlighting was handled as though the code was Java. And, since `/*` is Java's syntax to start a block comment, that's how it gets rendered.

You can [override the default syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) by using `<!-- language: lang-xml -->`, or any of the other languages shown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). I've updated the question with the correct language syntax, so you can find an example of it there.